# SOAP not working when I hook on "wp_loaded"

Tags: soap

I can make SOAP calls from by example the `woocommerce_payment_complete` hook or from the WP CLI.

If I make **the exact same call** from `wp_loaded` I get the SOAP Error: *failed to load external entity*

Is it bad practice to hook on `wp_loaded`? I understood that wordpress was fully loaded, I do this to receive callbacks from an external service but there's maybe a better way to do it? (I'm pretty new to Wordpress development).

```
add_action('wp_loaded', function() {
    $uri = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])[0];
    if ($uri == '/navision') {
        $payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
        _navision_callback_received($payload);
    }
});

add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', '_woocommerce_processing_order', 10, 1);

function _navision_callback_received($data) {
  /* SOAP CALL ----> error */
}

function _woocommerce_processing_order($orderId) {
 /* SOAP CALL ----> success */
}
```

Comment: Can you post the actual code which triggers the error?

Comment: like I said, the same exact call (i tried to hardcode it..) @cybmeta

Comment: Are you using SOAP to call a remote API? Or is a remote API using SOAP to call your site? `SOAP Error: failed to load external entity` doesn't make a lot of sense without more context and information, and without knowing what _navision_callback_received is supposed to do or return it's very difficult to answer. Is it the site or the remote service creating the error message?

Comment: I did find the problem now. It was like I thought related to wp_loaded. It's very weird. The user / password (authentication needed to call the remote API) were constants in wp-config.php and then $this->user = NAVISION_USER in my constructor. $this->user was empty when calling from wp_loaded

Comment: i fixed it with moving up my constants definitions in the beginning of wp-config.php. I guess it breaks sometimes when including wp-settings.php

Answer (score 1):

i fixed it with moving up my constants definitions in the beginning of wp-config.php. I guess it breaks sometimes when including wp-settings.php